# How is it more efficient to iterate over a string to put a combination of its symbol in a hashmap?

Tags: java

I want to iterate a string and in each step take from 1 to 4 characters and put these combinations in a hash map.

I wrote such a function:

```
public class AlgorithmImpl implements statAlgrithm{
    @Override
    public HashMap<String, Integer> analysis(String text) {
        HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        char[] chars = text.toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT).toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length-3; i++) {
            //map.putIfAbsent(chars[i],0);
            //map.computeIfPresent(chars[i], (k,v) -> v +1);
            map.putIfAbsent(String.valueOf(chars[i]),1);
            map.putIfAbsent(String.valueOf(chars[i]) + String.valueOf(chars[i+1]),1);
            map.putIfAbsent(String.valueOf(chars[i]) + String.valueOf(chars[i+1])+String.valueOf(chars[i+2]),1);
            map.putIfAbsent(String.valueOf(chars[i]) + String.valueOf(chars[i+1])+String.valueOf(chars[i+2])+String.valueOf(chars[i+3]),1);
            map.computeIfPresent(String.valueOf(chars[i]), (k,v) -> v +1);
            map.computeIfPresent(String.valueOf(chars[i]) + String.valueOf(chars[i+1])+String.valueOf(chars[i+2]), (k,v) -> v +1);
            map.computeIfPresent(String.valueOf(chars[i]) + String.valueOf(chars[i+1])+String.valueOf(chars[i+2])+String.valueOf(chars[i+3]), (k,v) -> v +1);
            map.computeIfPresent(String.valueOf(chars[i]) + String.valueOf(chars[i+1])+String.valueOf(chars[i+2])+String.valueOf(chars[i+3]), (k,v) -> v +1);
          
        }

        return map;
    }
}
```

But when the text is big enough, it doesn 't work as fast as I would like it to .And so I'm wondering if there is something better to do to make this function work faster?

Comment: One thing is you are concatenating the strings together multiple times when not necessary.    Also you are using put if absent and compute if present but you instead could use merge   map.merge(key, value, (oldvalue, newvalue) -> oldvalue + newvalue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are using String concatenation to build your substrings - use the
  String.substring() method to extract the substring.
- You are repeatedly building the substrings.  Do it once for each
  substring.
- You are calling calling `computeIfPresent` after `putIfAbsent`, so
  the first occurrence will produce a count of 2.  You can use `merge(sub, 1, (k,v) -> v += 1)` to capture both paths in a single statement.
- You are not accounting for the smaller substrings at the end of the
  text.  Limit the string length of a given substring by the remaining
  length of the text.

Comment: can recommend merge instead of compute here as you can use 
map.merge(k, v, Integer::sum)

Comment: @bgore good idea. updated answer.

Comment: @vsfDawg Thanks for the advice, but I didn't really understand your phrase: **You are not accounting for the smaller substrings at the end of the text. Limit the string length of a given substring by the remaining length of the text.** can you explain what does it mean?

Comment: @Omegon for each iteration you look at the block of the next 4 characters, so your for-loop condition uses `i < chars.length-3`.  So you don't process the last 3 characters the same as the rest of the `text` substrings because it doesn't start with a full 4 characters.  But it still contains substrings of length 3,2,1.  And the final 2 characters has substrings of 2 and 1 char length.  Depending on how your task is worded it may or may not matter.